# String reverse function

Tags: c++

why does the below function (f) work when i put `cout` in the function body but does't work when
i put `cout` after the function call

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void f(string str)
{
    int size=str.size();
    for (int i=0;i<size/2;i++)
    {
        char temp=str[i];
        str[i]=str[size-i-1];
        str[size-i-1]=temp;
    }
}
int main ()
{
    string a="abcd";
    f(a);
    cout<<a;   //output: abcd 
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void f(string str)
{
    int size=str.size();
    for (int i=0;i<size/2;i++)
    {
        char temp=str[i];
        str[i]=str[size-i-1];
        str[size-i-1]=temp;
    }
    cout<<str;
}
int main ()
{
    string a="abcd";
    f(a);  //output: dcba
}
```

I am new to programming so i don't know concepts like pointers which i am guessing is the problem here.

Comment: Hint: You're copying the string as an argument, then modifying a **local copy**. Consider `return str`.

Comment: *I am new to programming* - [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Put the output statement from the first example back into the second example (i.e., in `main` **after** the call to `f`. You'll see that nothing has changed. When you're analyzing something you don't understand (which we all end up doing much of the time), only change one thing at a time. So add the output statement to `f`, but don't remove the output statement from `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the variable `a` is not modified by the function `void f(string str)`. `f` takes a copy of the string and then uses that copy to reverse the string. This means that the original string `a` is unchanged.

If you want to make it so that `f` does not take a copy, you can pass the string by reference using the `&` operator.

`void f(string& str)` will use the same string for `a` and `str` as they will be referring to the same data in memory.

Comment: but why does the same code work for arrays ?

Comment: because an array decays into a pointer and the pointer makes it point to the same value. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay

Comment: aren't strings also arrays of characters ?

Comment: no a string is not an array of characters it is an object that contains an array of characters (Actually it's probably a pointer to some characters), but the important distinction is that it behave like an object and not an array so it doesn't decay